# Powershell rearrange items into a list seperated by comma

Tags: powershell

I have a variable which contains a number of items. For example,

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> $a
OU=Computers,DC=lala
OU=tset,DC=eat
```

How do I put the items together into a single string and separated by comma and each item with double quote? Here is the output I expect:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> $a
"OU=Computers,DC=lala","OU=tset,DC=eat"
```

Comment: `$a` is collection or what?

Comment: $a returns the following two items: OU=Computers,DC=lala
OU=tset,DC=eat

Comment: I understood @test. But my question is what is the type of `$a`?

Comment: Is $a some type of collection, such as an array where $a[0]='OU=Computers,DC=lala' and $a[1]='OU=tset,DC=eat', or is it a single string with an embedded carriage return or line feed? To find out, try issuing `$a.GetType().Name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  This is not the good programming example but it will give the required output:

```
 $newData= $a |% {"$("OU="+$_.OU),$("DC="+$_.DC)"}
 $newData
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array, you can try this:

```
($a | % { '"{0}"' -f $_  }) -join ","
```

Each element of the array is reformatted and the resulting stream is passed to the `-join` operator to concatenate with commas.

If you have a single string with embedded CRLF, try this:

```
(($a -split '\r\n') | % { '"{0}"' -f $_ }) -join ","
```

Here, we split the string into an array before passing it through the same logic as in the first example.